# Java conditional with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration, operators

```
int[] d = {97, 98, 71, 50, 82};
        if(d<=60){
        System.out.println(x.length);
        }
```

The purpose of this code is to print the number of students who passed this class (print values of 60 and above). In our case the output should print "4" but I have no idea how to achieve this. I tried a conditional statement but this seem rather difficult with the arrays being involved.

Any ideas? Should I try ArrayList?

Comment: Why should the output be 5 here?

Comment: Edited, it should be 4.

Comment: Oh boy.. that sure helps...

Comment: @user9578589 read some tutorial or a book for beginners

Comment: `Arrays.stream(d).filter(x -> x >= 60).toArray().length();` should work

Comment: @Dhruv It gave me compile time error.....

Comment: You will not be counted among the results of this program if you don't pay attention in class... this question shows essentially no attempt. You just jump from having an array to "this is what my result should be"

Comment: @user9578589 My bad, [see this](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoIwFETXcoq/bA00aKJACCSeAXfGRYWKxbaQ9kMghLNj42ryJm@m4xOPuua771IPvUXofMFGlIod86BW3Dm4Cz2swWEYX0rW4JCjj6mXDWguDanQStM@nsBt6yh48yANem6ggDVLQsjSEJJTCJc4hPS85d6oFodCs35ENvg5KkNu1vLFMYdWcE0ayt5SobBkhqiEGcoCrjFl2P89QpkSpsUP9W9bsO37Dw "Java (JDK 10) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xtratic sometimes I get stressed in class and it becomes hard to pay attention, it happens.

Comment: @user9578589 Just remember, this isn't a "do my homework" site. A huge part of coding is learning how to learn.

Comment: @xtratic I'm completely aware of that, I just happen to be in a tight situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you have just checked if the value of the array `d` is less than or equal to `60`, rather than checking how many of the values in `d` are greater than or equal to `60`. So the first issue is using `<` when you actually want `>`, so be sure to check your operators are correct.

You need to iterate over the `Array` and compare each value with the pass mark to work out if they passed. Each time they pass you should add to a counter, and when you have checked every value, output the pass counter value.

```
int numberPassed = 0; // counter to keep track of who passes
for (int score : d) {
    if (score >= 60) {
        numberPassed++; // pass score met so add one to counter
    }
}

System.out.println("Passed=" + numberPassed);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one and will note you if worked.

Comment: Yes, it worked. and you're right, iteration was the key. Thank you :)